# IE9 not Loading Javascript file from internal server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a API using MVC 4. In the config, has a attribute to point the server that holds the API's resources (JS, CSS, IMG, ...).

I ran into an issue with IE. When I get this page(partial code below) via AJAX, IE gets 2 errors: "SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101" and A syntax error on line 2. This same code works fine in Chrome and other browsers

```
@{
   string server = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"]; // http://SomeServerName
}
<script src="@Url.Content(@server + "/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I got around the issue by moving that Javascript file to the client page, I would prefer not to have to have the client of the API have Jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.min.js as required file.

P.S. All Objects and arrays had tailing commas removed.